# Iterating through pandas df with multiple row conditions

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, if-statement, optimization

I'm trying to work with a big dataframe (1M rows) where I need to set up high (1) and low (0)  profiles I build this function but it's quite long to go through all the columns and rows, how could I improve it ?
I've heard about vectorisation put don't know how to set it up.

Many thanks

```
#x is a dataframe
def flag_low(x):
    if x['EAN'] in list1:
        if (x['local_weekday'] >= 5 ):
            return 1
        elif ((x['local_hour'] <= 6) | (23 <= x['local_hour'])):
            return 1
        elif ((x['local_hour'] == 7) & ( x['local_minute'] < 30 )):
            return 1
        elif ((x['local_hour'] == 22) & ( 30 <= x['local_minute'] )):
            return 1
    elif x['EAN'] in list2:
        if (x['local_weekday'] >= 5 ):
            return 1
        elif ((x['local_hour'] <= 6) | (23 <= x['local_hour'])):
            return 1
    elif x['EAN'] in list3:
        if (x['local_weekday'] >= 5 ):
            return 1
        elif ((x['local_hour'] <= 6) | (22 <= x['local_hour'])):
            return 1
    elif x['EAN'] in  list4:
        if (x['local_weekday'] >= 5 ):
            return 1
        elif ((x['local_hour'] <= 6) | (22 <= x['local_hour'])):
            return 1
    elif x['EAN'] in list5:
        if (x['local_weekday'] >= 5 ):
            return 1
        elif ((x['local_hour'] <= 6) | (22 <= x['local_hour'])):
            return 1
    elif x['EAN'] in list6:
        if (x['local_weekday'] >= 5 ):
            return 1
        elif (x['local_time'] in be_holidays):
            return 1
        elif ((x['local_hour'] <= 5) | (21 <= x['local_hour'])):
            return 1
    elif x['EAN'] in list7:
        if (x['local_weekday'] >= 5 ):
            return 1
        elif (x['local_time'] in be_holidays):
            return 1
        elif ((x['local_hour'] <= 6) | (22 <= x['local_hour'])):
            return 1
    elif x['EAN'] in list8:
        if (x['local_weekday'] >= 5 ):
            return 1
        elif (x['local_time'] in be_holidays):
            return 1
        elif ((x['local_hour'] <= 6) | (22 <= x['local_hour'])):
            return 1
    elif x['EAN'] in list9:
        if (x['local_weekday'] >= 5 ):
            return 1
        elif (x['local_time'] in be_holidays):
            return 1
        elif ((x['local_hour'] <= 6) | (22 <= x['local_hour'])):
            return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

```
dataframe['BinLow'] = dataframe.apply(flag_low, axis = 1)
```

**Next steps**

I did what @Ade_1 explained but can't verify if it works due to a problem with :

> TypeError: Cannot convert type '<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>' to date.

on the line

```
(x['local_time'] in be_holidays)
```

How could I solve it ?

Comment: I did what @Ade_1 explained but can't verify if it works due to a problem with :
''TypeError: Cannot convert type '<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>' to date.''
on the '' (x['local_time'] in be_holidays) '' line

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a lot of if/else conditions, to vectorise you need the np.select().

For your nested ifs, you would have to chain them together

The syntax is as follows

```
condition= [
  (df['column'].isin(list1)) & (df['column']>= 5)
  #continue the conditions
 ]
choices= [
  1,
   # continue
     ]

 dataframe['BinLow']= np.select(condition, choices, default=0)
```

**Note**: the other of the condition should match your choices. Also, the default in the np.select() represents your last else statement.

Comment: You can reference this video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxWginnBklU